# Error using scipy.optimize.minimize / l-bfgs

Tags: python, scipy, nlp, mathematical-optimization

I'm attempting to train a log-linear language model. In order to do that I need to maximize a vector parameter.
I'm using this Loss function: 
[Loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEQ7t.png)

This is my code:

```
v0 = np.ones((len(tag_list), 1))

def first_argument(v, x, current_Tag):
    return np.dot(v, unigram_tag_feature_vector(current_Tag))

def second_argument(v, x, taglist):
    exp_ = 0
    for tag in taglist:
        exp_ += np.dot(v, unigram_tag_feature_vector(tag))
    return np.log(exp_)

def sum_func(ordered_text, taglist,  v):
    result = 0
    for (word, tag) in ordered_text:
        result += (-first_argument(v, 0, tag)- second_argument(v, 0, taglist))
    return result

def func(params, *args):
    ordered_text = args[0]
    taglist = args[1]
    v = params
    v_model= sum_func(ordered_text, taglist, v)
    print v_model
    return v

res = scipy.optimize.minimize(func, x0=v0, args=(ordered_text, tag_list))
```

And the error I get is:

```
line 610, in approx_fprime
    grad[k] = (f(*((xk + d,) + args)) - f0) / d[k]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The args are as follows:

```
ordered_text=[('In', 'IN'), ('an', 'DT'), ('Oct.', 'NNP'), ('19', 'CD'), ....]
tag_list=['CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'EX', 'FW'....]
```

The function `unigram_tag_feature_vector` returns the following output:

```
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

(a sparse vector, for any input)

Comment: I read this, but I can't see where I went wrong.
http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/frequent_errors.html

Comment: If you're using ipython, try [%debug](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#debugging) after the failure and find out all the values that cause the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that numpy is getting a vector someplace that it expects a scalar value.  Your objective function is returning the parameter vector `v`.  Do you mean instead for it to return the scalar `v_model`?

Comment: My bad, The function minimized should be the v_model.